# How to programmatically know when NodeJS application is running out of memory

Tags: node.js

How can I know when my application is running out of memory.

For me, I'm doing some video transcoding on the server and sometimes it leads to out of memory errors.

So, I wish to know when the application is running out of memory so I can immediately kill the Video Transcoder.

Thank you.

Comment: This will be hard to do precisely. Your best bet is to measure how much memory your process consumes by doing some OS syscalls.

Comment: Check the used heap memory. How are you transcoding the video? Are you using streams or buffering the input/output? I would suggest ffmpeg when it comes to work with media files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how much memory is being used with the built-in `process` module.

```js
const process = require("process");
```

The `process` module has a method called [`memoryUsage`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage), which shows info on the memory usage in Node.js.

```js
console.log(process.memoryUsage());
```

When you run the code, you should see an object with all of the information needed for memory usage!

```
$ node index.js
{
  rss: 4935680,
  heapTotal: 1826816,
  heapUsed: 650472,
  external: 49879,
  arrayBuffers: 9386
}
```

---

Here is some insight on each property.

- `rss` - (Resident Set Size) Amount of space occupied in the main memory device.
- `heapTotal` - The total amount of memory in the V8 engine.
- `heapUsed` - The amount of memory used by the V8 engine.
- `external` - The memory usage of C++ objects bound to JavaScript objects (managed by V8).
- `arrayBuffers` - The memory allocated for `ArrayBuffer`s and `Buffer`s.

---

For your question, you might need to use `heapTotal` and `heapUsed`. Depending on the value, you can then shut the service down. For example:

```js
const process = require("process");

const mem = process.memoryUsage();
const MAX_SIZE = 50; // Change the value to what you want

if ((mem.heapUsed / 1000000) >= MAX_SIZE) {
  videoTranscoder.kill(); // Just an example...
}
```

The division by one million part just converts bytes to megabytes (B to MB).

<sub>Change the code to what you like - this is just an example.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Use `v8.getHeapStatistics()`. It is more informative than `process.memoryUsage()`. In particular, it includes `heap_size_limit` which tells you the true limits of your Node.js process's memory.

```js
import * as v8 from 'node:v8';

const maxHeap = v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit;

// get the percentage of the max heap currently in use
function getPercentOfMaxHeapInUse() {
    return v8.getHeapStatistics().used_heap_size / maxHeap;
}

// error out if over 80% of the heap is in use
if (getPercentOfMaxHeapInUse() > 0.8) {
    throw new Error('using too much memory');
}
```

You can modify the max heap space with the `--max_old_space_size` flag, like this:

```bash
# set the heap max to 3 GB (1024 * 3)
node --max_old_space_size=3072 index.js
```